# NCurses: Setting last character on screen (without scrolling enabled)

Tags: ncurses

Assume you have a NCurses Window (could be a subwindow) with dimensions ROWS and COLS. 
How do I set the character at ROWS-1 and COLS-1. If I use waddstr at this position with one character it doesn't work (throws a user exception). I assume this is because the cursor is moved to a position outside the window?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour seems to be intentional:
http://old.nabble.com/Setting-last-character-on-screen-%28without-scrolling-enabled%29-to33969235.html

> checking portability:
>           Solaris 10 returns ERR
>           IRIX64     returns ERR
>           HPUX 11.23 returns OK
>           Tru64      returns ERR
>           AIX    6.1 returns OK
>
> Though HPUX implemented SVr4, it was the last (and some of its
>   differences from the other systems demonstrate that the implementers
>   relied more on documentation than on cross-checking).  Tru64 is
>   technically the best of the above listed; Solaris has a lot of code
>   rot.  So I've found no reason to change the quirk.
>
> --  Thomas E. Dickey